# Extract JSON content without object in java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I want to extract the contents of JSON as a string from the response coming from the server. **The JSON does not have any object in it.** 
Following is the JSON.

```
{
"name": "some name",
"user_id": "some_id",
"some_other_values": "value",
"some_other_values": "value@gmail.com",
"some_other_values": "value",
"some_other_values": "value",
"some_other_values": "value"
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: is you want to parse this JSON?

Comment: Yeah, I want to extract it's contents as a string and save their values in Preference in  android. @MaheshGawhane

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 try{
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        String name= obj.getString("name");
        String user_id= obj.getString("user_id");
        String value= obj.getString("value");

       /
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**to save data in sharedpref like this**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("name", name);        
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to getString from your json response string. use this code to pares your json.

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    String name= obj.getString("name")
    String user_id= obj.getString("user_id")
    String value= obj.getString("some_other_values")
```

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod its not copy paste. i am posting my own code.

Comment: Add `try-catch` block

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid try-catch for null pointer exception and if you are not sure of the keys then you may use optString instead of getString both of them return the same result String but getString will give null value if the key will not exist in your JSONObject whereas optString will give empty string for non-existence of key.Try this:

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
    String name= obj.optString("name")
    String user_id= obj.optString("user_id")
    String value= obj.optString("value")
```